# How to show a dropdown over a modal using Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I'm using Tailwind CSS and I want to show the white dropdown over the modal.
I tried using `z-index` but I can't make it work.

Any ideas?

[image: modal]

This is my modal code:

```
<TransitionRoot as="template" :show="isOpen">
<Dialog as="div" class="inset-0 fixed overflow-y-auto">
  <div class="flex min-h-screen text-center px-4 pt-4 pb-20 items-end justify-center sm:p-0 sm:block">
    <TransitionChild as="template" enter="ease-out duration-300" enter-from="opacity-0" enter-to="opacity-100" leave="ease-in duration-200" leave-from="opacity-100" leave-to="opacity-0">
      <DialogOverlay class="bg-gray-975 bg-opacity-85 inset-0 transition-opacity fixed" />
    </TransitionChild>

    <!-- This element is to trick the browser into centering the modal contents. -->
    <span class="hidden sm:h-screen sm:inline-block sm:align-middle" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>
    <TransitionChild as="template" enter="ease-out duration-300" enter-from="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95" enter-to="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100" leave="ease-in duration-200" leave-from="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100" leave-to="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95">
      <div class="rounded-lg shadow-xl text-left transform transition-all text-gray-850 inline-block align-bottom overflow-hidden sm:max-w-lg sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:align-middle dark:text-gray-200">
        ...
      </div>
    </TransitionChild>
  </div>
</Dialog>
```

And this is my dropdown code:

```
<Listbox v-model="selectedPerson">
<div class="mt-1 relative z-50">
  <ListboxButton
    class="bg-white rounded-lg cursor-default shadow-md text-left w-full py-2 pr-10 pl-3 relative sm:text-sm focus:outline-none focus-visible:border-indigo-500 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-opacity-75 focus-visible:ring-offset-orange-300 focus-visible:ring-offset-2">
    <span class="block truncate">{{ selectedPerson.name }}</span>
    <span class="flex pr-2 inset-y-0 right-0 absolute items-center pointer-events-none">
      <SelectorIcon class="h-5 text-gray-400 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
    </span>
  </ListboxButton>

  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `overflow-y-auto` from modal component...

Comment: It would be very helpful if you move your code snippet in stackblitz and share link with us. Thank You

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, this will not solve the problem

Comment: We don't have any news from OP here so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ there is no way to proceed any further anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove class `overflow-hidden` from `<div class="rounded-lg shadow-xl text-left transform transition-all text-gray-850 inline-block align-bottom overflow-hidden sm:max-w-lg sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:align-middle dark:text-gray-200">`.
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-ride-6xg6p)

Comment: Yes, but this solution removes the rounded borders

Answer (score 1):

Change the class that sets the position of the child element from `absolute` to `fixed`